# postgreSQL getting column values as new column and adding

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns

I have the following table

| ident | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | X | 1 |
| A1 | Y | 2 |
| A1 | X | 6 |
| A2 | X | 2 |
| A2 | Z | 3 |

What i need is a new table which should look like:

| ident | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 7 | 2 | 0 |
| A2 | 2 | 0 | 3 |

so it should give me for every distinct id a sum of all the existing names.
But the columns with are build out of the names should be build automaticly.

i have try

```
SELECT
  ident ,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (name = 'X') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS X
FROM
  mytable
GROUP BY ident 
ORDER BY ident
```

but with this code i have to make the columns and just can set the sum to 0 or 1.

Thx

Comment: It is called ["pivot"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+pivot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation, which in Postgres looks like this:

```
select ident,
       sum(count) filter (where name = 'X') as x_sum,
       sum(count) filter (where name = 'Y') as y_sum,
       sum(count) filter (where name = 'Z') as z_sum
from mytable
group by ident;
```

The `FILTER` clause is Standard SQL, but Postgres is one of the few databases that actually supports it.  You can, of course, do the same thing with `CASE` expressions, but `FILTER` gives the optimizer more hints that can help performance (and many people find it cleaner).

Comment: is there a way that i dont have to write all the name? so that they are picked up automatically?

Comment: @hahakomisch . . . You could construct the query as a string and then execute it.  That is called dynamic SQL.

Comment: ok thx for the idea. never heard of that before as i am very new to sql.

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for sum of count:

```
SELECT
  ident ,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (name = 'X') THEN count ELSE NULL END) AS X,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (name = 'Y') THEN count ELSE NULL END) AS Y,
  SUM(CASE WHEN (name = 'Z') THEN count ELSE NULL END) AS Z
FROM
  mytable
GROUP BY ident 
ORDER BY ident
```